# Post individual files from archive using Python requests module

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, zip

I am using the Python requests module to post data to a server. For the data, I have an archive, that I'm filtering through and posting all files except .txt files. My code is posted below. Right now, the files get uploaded successfully, but the directory structure of the archive is preserved.

Is there a way to upload just the base file without uploading all of the subdirectories as well?

```
import zipfile
import requests

archive = 'my_archive.zip'
url = 'https://example.com'
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(archive)
files = zf.namelist()
files = list(filter(lambda x: not x.endswith('/'), files))
files = list(filter(lambda x: not x.lower().endswith(('.txt')), files))
for f in files:
    response = requests.post(url,
                            auth=usrPass)                                   
                            data=zf.read(f))
```

Comment: Are you sure this is what you do in your actual code? Because you don't seem to be passing a filename anywhere in your `requests.post` call.

Comment: My url is actually a little more complicated. It includes a filename parameter so each file would go to a unique url. eg. `url = 'https://example.com/data/archive/files/{filename}'`

Comment: And this filename is `f` (control variable of your `for` loop)? In this case, it contains the whole path, not just filename. Doing `filename = f.split('/')[-1]` should probably fix it.

Comment: Yes, the `filename` is what you described. My issue is that the whole path needs to be read by zipfile. And that ends up creating all of the paths instead of just uploading the file.

Comment: Ahh actually nevermind. I see that I didn't change the filename to just grab the last part. Thanks for your help.